# VISA sponsorship happens each April in the US

Tags: united-states, visa

I got this response from a former prospective employer Dec 2019.

"Unfortunately, it is too late to sponsor someone for a new visa, as that only happens each April in the US."

Does it mean companies can only apply for VISA sponsorship for their potential employees from outside the US once a year and only in April every year?

Comment: Check with the visa issuers... best source - up to date and accurate.

Comment: It may be useful to ask the employer when you should apply. They may have a fixed schedule for processing foreign applications, just as employers who hire new graduates have a schedule that is linked to the academic year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you're speaking of the H-1B visa, based on the April-only points.  The application period begins in April and there is a limit on the number of these visas that may be issued in a year.

While technically these visas can be applied for throughout the year, there is a rule in place that stops applications from being accepted once the limit has been passed (or some buffer above the limit, maybe).  After the first week in April, if this threshold has been passed, applications will not be accepted until the following year.

This visa has hit this limit quickly every year for many years now.  In part it is due to popularity of the visa.  It is also due to those filing knowing they must do so in the first week of April in order to not be cut off.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer I am looking for!